# Can't install JDK 7

Tags: java, windows, java-7

I can install the JRE 7 without any problem.  However when I try to install JDK 7, nothing happens.  I am currently running Win7 64-bit.  When I double click on the downloaded file, a dialog box pops up asking me if I want to run the application, I click "run" and then nothing happens.  I don't even get an error message.  JDK 6 installs just fine.  I tried uninstalling all versions of Java, and the installing JDK 7, but the same thing happens.  I've even installed JDK 7 on another computer just fine, and then used that file to try and install on my laptop, but the same thing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Later, pre-release versions of the installer such as 7u6 do not have this problem.
Download pre-prerelease versions here: http://jdk7.java.net/download.html

Reference: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7145760

Answer (score 0):

The [Oracle bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7145760) details how to fix this:

(I've modified it to use the latest stable version (`u05`)

> Suggested Workaround:
> For Win7, here were the steps used to get it to
> install based on the above instructions.
>
> 1. goto c:\Users[your user]
> 2. create jdk1.7.0_05_combo directory
> 3. right click on folder and select permissions
> 4. click advanced button
> 5. deny delete/delete sub for each listed role/user
> 6. run downloader  installer
> 7. goto jdk1.7.0_05 and run the java_jdk.exe (no need to copy to another dir)

See here for more info:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7145760