# Can't install jdk-7u5-windows-x64, double-click does nothing

Tags: java, installation, double-click, java-7

I'm facing a weird problem with Oracle jdk-7u5 installation. After downloading the file from [oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1637583.html), I just can't run it. When I double-click the file *jdk-7u5-windows-x64* , nothing happens. Nothing at all! When I try to install *jre-7u5-windows-x64*, it goes normally! The problem seems to be only with jdk.
Any suggestions ?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Have you tried other JDKs? Have you tried to download the file again? What does the system events log say?

Comment: Disable your virus scanner. Might being blocked for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on the file to "Run as administrator"?

Comment: I haven't tried other JDKs yet, but I'm working on that. I tried to download the file several times and I disabled my firewall.. but the problem remains

Comment: DennisG, I've tried that too.

Comment: Ok, right-click on the file to bring up the properties dialog. Near the blottom, you might see a button labeled "Unblock". If the button is there and enabled, Click the "Unblock" button. Then click "OK" on the dialog and try executing again.

Comment: Hum, it didn't work either. For some reason, jdk-6u33 works fine. I can open its installation window normally. But jdk-7u5 still doesn't react, even after trying all the suggestions given so far. I appreciate each one of them.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725580/cant-install-jdk-7/11226062